# Displaying an image in WPF (without Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to display an image in WPF (whether by defining it as a resource or simply by referring to the path and not defining a resource) but the image doesn't show in my application. I have a JPG image with the name 'MyImage' in a folder called 'Images'. I've seen a lot of answers saying that I need to set the build action to resource in Visual Studio but my computer cannot handle Visual Studio or any of the alternate IDE's so I'm basically doing this using cmd and Sublime Text as a text Editor.
Here's the code for MainWindow.xaml :

```
<Window x:Class="WPF106.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF106"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="600">

    <StackPanel>

        <TextBlock Text="Dummy1"/>
        <Image Source="/Images/MyImage.jpg" Height="150" />
        <TextBlock Text="Dummy2" />

    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

[The project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kO0jC.jpg)

[The application result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cv5mR.jpg)

P.S. I have tried using Visual Studio but unfortunately that is not at all an option so if anyone could come up with a solution to this without using it (and preferably using the image as a resource), please let me know.

Comment: The relative path you use, '/Images/MyImage.jpg', doesn't exist where your running application expects to find it. My thought is that you need your images folder under the same directory as the .exe that is produced when you run your application, most likely in the '/bin/' or '/bin/debug/' folder.

Comment: @quaabaam Didn't work.

Comment: Try setting the full path to the image file.

Comment: Try the following: in **WPF106.csproj** add `<ItemGroup><Resource Include="Images\MyImage.jpg" /></ItemGroup>` , then in `<Window.Resources>` add `<BitmapImage x:Key="MyImageKey" UriSource="Images/MyImage.jpg" />`, then your image become `<Image Source="{StaticResource MyImageKey}" Height="150" />`

Comment: While `<ItemGroup><Resource Include="Images\MyImage.jpg"/></ItemGroup>` would work with an SDK-Style project file, the BitmapImage and StaticResource part is redundant. `<Image Source="Images/MyImage.jpg"/>` would then of course also work - perhaps without the leading slash.

Comment: @Khiro Clemens It worked! Thank you! Doing that ItemGroup thing in the .csproj file is an equivalent to setting the folders build action to resources, right?

Comment: @Clemens I agree that `BitmapImage` and `StaticResource` are redundant for single image but if same image is used in multiple places in the window/application then it make sense to share it as a static resource which help to avoid hard-coded paths everywhere. As for SDK-style project, I'm not very familiar with it yet but I think the equivalent of `Resource` is `EmbeddedResource`?

Comment: No, Resource is ok. EmbeddedResource is wrong.

Comment: @Khiro Clemens So how can I add a whole folder as an ItemGroup in my .csproj? Cuz adding every single file one by one might be pretty redundant and weird.

Comment: As far as i know, that's not possible.